# Como enviar dados do formulário pelo JavaScript e redirecionar

Tags: php, javascript, html

Preciso fazer com que o meu formulário envie dados para uma outra página do servidor para que ele insira no MySQL porém que redirecione o usuário para outra página mas antes receba uma mensagem de sucesso. Porém, por algum motivo, não esta aparecendo a mensagem.

**Formulário + JS:**

```js
$().ready(function() {

    function onFinish() {
        //here you can do something, sent the form to server via ajax and show a success message with swal
        var nomep = $("#nome");
        var descricao = $("#descricao");
        var ponto_minimo = $("#ponto_minimo");
        var ponto_maximo = $("#ponto_maximo");
        var quantidade = $("#quantidade");
        var localizacao = $("#localizacao");
        var categoria_id = $("#categoria_id");
        var usuario = $("#usuario");
        var data = $("#data");
        var justificativa = $("#justificativa");

        $.post("assets/php/alterar-produto.php", {
            nome: nomep,
            descricao: descricao,
            ponto_minimo: ponto_minimo,
            ponto_maximo: ponto_maximo,
            quantidade: quantidade,
            localizacao: localizacao,
            categoria_id: categoria_id,
            usuario: usuario,
            data: data,
            justificativa: justificativa
        });

        setTimeout(function() {
            swal({
                title: "Sucesso!",
                text: "Alterações salvas com êxito",
                type: "success"
            }, function() {
                window.location = "redirectURL";
            });
        }, 1000);

    }
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="#">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nome</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Insira um nome" class="form-control" value="<?=utf8_encode($produto['nome'])?>" name="nome">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
       ...Demais campos...
    </form>
```

**Form Completa:**

```html
<div class="content">
  <form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Nome</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Insira um nome" class="form-control" value="<?=utf8_encode($produto['nome'])?>" name="nome">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="descricao">Descrição</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Insira a Descrição" rows="3" name="descricao"><?=utf8_encode($produto['descricao'])?></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Ponto mínimo</label>
          <input type="number" placeholder="Insira o Ponto mínimo" class="form-control" value="<?=utf8_encode($produto['ponto_minimo'])?>" name="ponto_minimo">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Ponto máximo</label>
          <input type="number" placeholder="Insira o Ponto máximo" class="form-control" value="<?=utf8_encode($produto['ponto_maximo'])?>" name="ponto_maximo">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Quantidade</label>
          <input type="number" placeholder="Insira uma quantidade" class="form-control" value="<?=utf8_encode($produto['quantidade'])?>" name="quantidade">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Localização</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Insira o Local" class="form-control" value="<?=utf8_encode($produto['localizacao'])?>" name="localizacao">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <?php $categorias = listaCategorias($conexao); ?>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <select name="categoria_id" class="selectpicker" data-title="Categoria" data-style="btn-default btn-block" data-menu-style="dropdown-blue">
                                        <?php foreach($categorias as $categoria) :
                                            $essaEhACategoria = $produto['categoria_id'] == $categoria['id'];
                                            $selecao = $essaEhACategoria ? "selected='selected'" : "";
                                            ?>
                                            <option value="<?=$categoria['id']?>" <?=$selecao?>>
                                                <?=utf8_encode($categoria['nome'])?>
                                            </option>
                                        <?php endforeach ?>
                                    </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br/>

    <input type="hidden" name="usuario" value="<?=$usuario?>">

    <input type="hidden" value="<?=$data = date('Y-m-d H:i'); ?>" name="data">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?=$produto['id']?>" name="id">

    <hr>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="justificativa">Justificativa</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Insira a Justificativa" rows="3" name="justificativa" required></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 ">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-info center-block" onclick="onFinish()">Enviar</button>
      </div>
    </div>


  </form>
```

Inclusão do SweetAlert

```html
<!-- Sweet Alert 2 plugin -->
<script src="assets/js/sweetalert2.js"></script>
```

link do que está no arquivo SweetL

https://pastebin.com/EM0nWWu0

Answer (score 2):

O método `swal()` tem um *overload* que recebe uma `function`, que executa a ação após o clique no botão "Ok"

Segue um exemplo **utilizando a biblioteca que você usa, [Sweet Alert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/)**

```js
 setTimeout(function() {
            swal({
              title: "Sucesso!",
              text: "Alterações salvas com êxito",
              type: "success"
            }, function() {
              window.location = "redirectURL";
            });
          }, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert-dev.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Javascript:

```js
$().ready(function() {

      function onFinish() {
        //here you can do something, sent the form to server via ajax and show a success message with swal
        var nomep = $("#nome");
        var descricao = $("#descricao");
        var ponto_minimo = $("#ponto_minimo");
        var ponto_maximo = $("#ponto_maximo");
        var quantidade = $("#quantidade");
        var localizacao = $("#localizacao");
        var categoria_id = $("#categoria_id");
        var usuario = $("#usuario");
        var data = $("#data");
        var justificativa = $("#justificativa");

        $.post("assets/php/alterar-produto.php", {
          nome: nomep,
          descricao: descricao,
          ponto_minimo: ponto_minimo,
          ponto_maximo: ponto_maximo,
          quantidade: quantidade,
          localizacao: localizacao,
          categoria_id: categoria_id,
          usuario: usuario,
          data: data,
          justificativa: justificativa
        });

        setTimeout(function() {
          swal({
            title: "Sucesso!",
            text: "Alterações salvas com êxito",
            type: "success"
          }, function() {
            window.location = "redirectURL";
          });
        }, 1000);

      }
    }
```

html:

```html
<form method="POST" action="#">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Nome</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Insira um nome" class="form-control" value="<?=utf8_encode($produto['nome'])?>" name="nome">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  ...Demais campos...
</form>
```

Comment: Preciso colocar meu botão como tipo "Submit"?

Comment: Quando eu clico no botão submit não acontece nada

Comment: Naturalmente ele vai fazer a requisção assincrona e ativar o swal, depois que clicar no swal ele vai redirecionar.

Comment: Mas @LuhanSalimena se você não mudou seu antigo código, ele vai fazer o mesmo que antes, porém eu apenas adicionei um "parametro novo" que redireciona quando clica no aviso.

Comment: Então preciso tirar a action do form?

Comment: @LuhanSalimena Antes, ele mostrava o aviso? Se sim, quando você clicava no aviso ele não redirecionava correto?

Comment: Não , nem antes nem agora

Comment: @LuhanSalimena Aai fica dificil kkk, você não disse que o problema era o submit. Mas beleza, vamos resolver seu problema !

Comment: testei novamente aqui e a inserção e nem a mensagem funcionam

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64266/discussion-between-luhan-salimena-and-leonardo-bonetti).

Comment: Consegui enviar os dados mas não consigo fazer a mensagem aparecer

Comment: Vou editar o Javascript, corrige ai no seu e ve se funciona.

Comment: @LuhanSalimena você alterou o seu JAVASCRIPT? edita a pergunta por favor? valeu

Comment: Editei a pergunta com o código

Comment: @LuhanSalimena você está importando a biblioteca Sweet Alert certinho ?

Comment: Utilizo o código que veio junto ao meu design irei colocar na pergunta

Answer (score 1):

use a função setTimeout, vai aparecer a mensagem e depois de um tempo, no caso 2 segundos (2000) vai redirecionar para a sua página.:

```
window.setTimeout("location.href='http://seusite.com'", 2000);
```